# Reading, grouping and sorting nodes in an html doc using agility pack

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to build a class that will read, group and sort an html document based on another web site.

I will display the things I have up to now. Here's a sample of how the web page is constructed (keep in mind that it is just "how" it is built, I've rewrote the whole thing):

```
<tr>
            <td id="ab100_ab100_ab100_Main_Sub_Sub_objComponent" class="compContainer">
                <table class="objDetails" style="position: relative; margin: auto;">
 <tr>
<div class="smallSetup" style="margin-top: 10px;">
    <b class="ft"><b></b></b>
    <div id="ab100_ab100_ab100_Main_Sub_Sub_firstProp" class="row">
       <div class="label">
           First Name:</div>
       <div class="value">
           Albert Trebla</div>
    </div>

    <div id="ab100_ab100_ab100_Main_Sub_Sub_secondProp" class="row">
        <div class="label" style="line-height:25px;">
           Second Year:</div>
        <div class="value">
           <img src="/Setup/Images.ashx?size=medium&amp;name=5&amp;type=symbol" alt="5" align="absbottom" /><img src="/Setup/Images.ashx?size=medium&amp;name=W&amp;type=symbol" alt="Second" align="absbottom" />
     </div>
     <div id="ab100_ab100_ab100_Main_Sub_Sub_thirdProp" class="row" style="height:15px; position:relative;">
         <div class="label" style="font-size:.7em;">
             Classy Stuff:</div>
         <div class="value">
             7<br /><br /></div>
     </div>

     <div id="ab100_ab100_ab100_Main_Sub_Sub_fourthProp" class="row">
         <div class="label">
             Weather:</div>
         <div class="value">
             Cloudy  — Might Rain</div>
         </div>
     <div id="ab100_ab100_ab100_Main_Sub_Sub_fifthProp" class="row">
         <div class="label">
             Front Text:</div>
         <div class="value">
             <div class="frontTextBox">Opened</div><div class="frontTextBox">The shop is opened when the bridges are lowered.</div></div>
     </div>
     <div id="ab100_ab100_ab100_Main_Sub_Sub_sixthProp" class="row">
         <div class="label">
              Flavor:</div>
         <div id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_SubContent_SubContent_FlavorText" class="value">
              <div class="frontTextBox"><i>"This taste good!"</i></div></div>
     </div>
```

And so on.

Now here's how I structured my code in my app:

```
HtmlWeb loader = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = loader.Load(stringUrl);
HtmlNode parentNode = doc.GetElementById(ab100_ab100_ab100_Main_Sub_Sub_objComponent);

HtmlNodeCollection allNodes = parentNode.SelectNodes(".//div[@class='row']");
```

And I have my collection of divs, but I'm unable to make the next step. The first thing to understand is that the layout of the html code up there will change, so sometimes the firstProp will not show and sometimes it's the sixth prop, and so on.

So I though to check if the node's attributes is "label":

```
foreach (HtmlNode htmlNode in allNodes)
{
    if (htmlNode.Attributes["class"].Value == "label")
    {

    }
}
```

But I don't know how to check the value after since the next sibling is an empty div. And I don't know much how HtmlAgilityPack work, so I wonder if there is an easier way to get this.

Can anyone advise me on how to proceed, or if what I'm doing is wrong and how to correct it?

*** EDIT ***

I have changed the line:

```
HtmlNodeCollection allNodes = parentNode.SelectNodes(".//div[@class='row']");
```

so that now my collection is narrowed only to the div I would get. But I still need to read when I get a div with class "label", read what value it is (ex: Front Text), and if that's Front Text, get the following div with class "value".

Comment: What data exactly do you want to extract from the original HTML?

Comment: I will need every <div class="value"> available from the original HTML doc.

Comment: But I cannot simply filter by "value" because the value obtained does not indicate if this data belongs to Weather, Classy Stuff, or other.

Comment: You want a dictionary of all DIV label and DIV value inner text?

Comment: Oh! That would be great! How could I do that?

Comment: Wait. I just thought about this. This won't do, because as the example shows, I will sometimes not have text, but rather <img src>.

Comment: What would be awesome would be that I can actually "read" when the node obtained is a "label", read what value it is, then get to the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you learn a bit of [XPATH](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/) which is supported by the Html Agility Pack, and allows for  concise queries over the HTML DOM. For example, the following code:

```
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.Load("test.htm");

    HtmlNode node = doc.GetElementbyId("ab100_ab100_ab100_Main_Sub_Sub_objComponent");
    foreach (HtmlNode row in node.SelectNodes(".//div[@class='row']"))
    {
        Console.Write(row.SelectSingleNode("div[@class='label']").InnerText.Trim());
        Console.WriteLine(row.SelectSingleNode("div[@class='value']").InnerText.Trim());
    }
```

Will output this:

```
First Name:Albert Trebla
Second Year:
Classy Stuff:7
Weather:Cloudy  - Might Rain
Front Text:OpenedThe shop is opened when the bridges are lowered.
Flavor:"This taste good!"
```

if you need HTML inside the value or label div, then you can again issue XPATH queries from there.

Comment: Sound advice, I will check this out, and work around this. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I tried a few things, but I still can't figure out how this works. I have succeeded thanks to your advide at narrowing all the values I need using the 

HtmlNodeCollection allNodes = parentNode.SelectNodes(".//div[@class='row']"); 

Line, but then I need to check if there's a node which has a class 'label' whose value is, for example, Front Text, then if that is true I need to get the value in the div accordingly